# How to make each script separate to each initiation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

So I am currently Trying to create a zombies game, where I have a script written that would enable a hitting animation if it was "close" to the player.
The code for this script is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class ZombieNavMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform movePositionTransform;

    private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

    private Animator animator;

    static bool close;

    private void Start()
    {
        movePositionTransform = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!close)
        {
            navMeshAgent.destination = movePositionTransform.position;
            animator.SetBool("Close", false);
        } 
        if (close)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Close", true);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Should hit");
            close = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Should not hit");
            close = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem in here is that, if one zombie Enters Trigger, and another zombie Exit Trigger, the bool value close would be set to false, so both would perform walking animation; it should be the "close" zombie hitting animation, and the far zombie walking animation.

Comment: On which gameobject  does this script has been attached?

Comment: On The Zombie Prefab

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the word `static` from `static bool close;`

`static` means there is only one of that thing shared by all versions and instances of the class.

Comment: As far as I remember I did this, but still it acts as all of them are one gameObject, I am trying to think of a way to (by setting a parameter) to make each instance unique

Comment: Well the static will definitely cause this, so fix that first or anything else you change in an attempt to find the cause will be pointless.